# Bounty still remains unassigned to responder

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, bounties

I asked a question regarding debugging a VB6 web application on Windows 7 64-bit that remained unanswered for over a year. I had offerred bounties previously although still did not receive an answer.

I recently updated the question and offerred a bounty of 300. Again, noone answer although I accepted the answer from someone who obviously showed great effort at replicating the problem and describing the underlying cause. The bounty expired and I accepted the answer a few hours after.

However, the bounty still remains unassigned although it was taken from my reputation. Where did the bounty go?

The original question is posted here:
[How can I debug a VB6 IIS Application on Windows 7 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728958/how-can-i-debug-a-vb6-iis-application-on-windows-7-64-bit)

Comment: It's gone. :) ..

Comment: According to the link I had up to 24 hours after the bounty expired:
"1 week = 7 days.

As of June 2011, bounty offerers may award bounties up to 24 hours after the bounty period ends, to allow them to evaluate answers posted at the end of the bounty period." Since I accepted the answer a few hours afterward it should have been assigned.

Comment: Rob's point is that "accepting an answer" and "assigning a bounty" are two entirely independent/separate things.

Comment: In this case it looks as though the problem was that the condition of having a score of 2 or more was not met. Seems silly that the person offerring the bounty accepting an answer shortly after the bounty expired would not reward at least half bounty to the user.  Thanks for your clarification as it does answer my question.